# How do i launch android app if my app package name is same as existing app in app store?

Tags: android

I am going to launch one app in app-store. If my application package is same with any of the application in the google app store, my application will replace another application when installing in our device. I don't know what are the packages are available in google app store. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: have you try to upload your app on app store? app store would reject your app since your app has same package name as one of the existing app and different signature...

Comment: hi praful. till now i didn't upload any app in app store.

Comment: what I was trying to say that the apps store would not let you upload a new app that has same package name as the existing app package name..

Comment: different signature in the sense?

Comment: your package name should be unique, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions

Answer (score 3):

It's a non-issue. You can't submit an app to Google Play that collides with another app with the same package name.

Comment: Isn't that implicit in my answer? I think it is. If so, why the down vote?

Answer (score 1):

Developer are allowed to upload new version of their existing apps on the play store.The new version needs to have higher version number and needs to be singed with the same key as the existing version..

Play store use package name to identify an particular app.. Now when you upload an new app with same package name as the existing app's package name.. Play store would assume that you are trying to upload a new version of the existing app.. Now it would check if the signature/key used for singing is same as the key used to sign the existing version or not.. if they are not same it would give you An error..

This check also saves anyone else to replace your app with their own app on play store..

So in short you can not upload an new app that has the same package name as one of the existing app..

Comment: have we to change our package name until it is unique like our gmail user name?

Comment: try to use scheme like.. `com.<your_company_name>.project_name.<xxx>` there are high probability that this would be available..

Answer (score 0):

Apps in Google Play are identified by their package name. Each package name can only be used by a single app; no two apps in the market can have the same package name.

Once you upload your app to Google Play, its package name will forever be tied to your Google Play publisher account.